# Zabbix - how add item and triggers to discovery rules

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I am inexperienced in zabbix and I have a question.
I made a clone for item and trigger one already existing in zabbix.
Unfortunately, I don't know how and where I can connect it to be governed by specific Discovery rules.
Someone help me?
Screen from zabbix.

[image]